# Is there any way to detect if a nullable parameter is present in a Nancy request body

Tags: nancy

**Background**

I have a web server using Nancy 1.4.3. Nancy model binding is used to deserialize data from an HTTP request with a json body. See example below.

**Example**

Endpoint in server:

```
private class ARequestBody
{
    public int? Parameter1 { get; set; }
    public int? Parameter2 { get; set; }
}

[Post("examplerequest")]
public Response AMethod()
{
    var body = this.Bind<ARequestBody>

    //Do stuff with data in body
    var foo = body.Parameter1;
    var bar = body.Parameter2;

    return new Response();
}
```

Request to endpoint:

```
Method: POST
Path: [server_address_etc]/examplerequest
Body:
{
    "Parameter1" : 123,
    "Parameter2" : null
}
```

If a request is made to this endpoint where for example Parameter1 is null in the request body, body.Parameter1 will understandably have the value null after binding. However, if Parameter1 is not included in the request, body.Parameter1 will also be null.

**Question**

Is there any way to detect if a parameter is included in a request body? If possible, I want to be able to discern between:

1. a nullable parameter being included in a request body but with the value null
2. if the parameter is not included in the request body at all.